# Issue with my right outer join in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Outer joins don't seem to work whether I use a left outer join or right outer join:

```
SELECT * FROM `event_orchestra_musicians` eom
right outer join `orchestra_instruments` oi on eom.instrument_id = oi.oi_id
where event_id = 2
order by instrument_id
```

Orchestra_instruments contains different instruments with a unique ID i.e.:

1. Violin
2. Viola
3. Harp
4. Piccolo

Event_Orchestra_Musicians is a look up table to join musicians to an instrument i.e.:

```
musician_id, instrument_id, event_id, 
1 1 2
2 1 2
3 3 2
4 2 2
```

When I do any outer join, using the data in those tables, I would get the results of an inner join (Piccolo wouldn't show up with a null musician_id, it wont show up at all). Is there something I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

**So I did some monkeying around. The issue seems to be because there is a record in the events_orchestra_musicians table with an event_id of 5 and an instrument_id of 7. If I remove that record, then the outer join works. What I don't get is if that record is there and I use the where clause to look for event_id = 2, why does it matter if there's a record in there with an instrument_id of 7 if its event_id is 5?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select oi.oi_id, oi.instrument_name, eom.musician_id
from orchestra_instruments oi
left join event_orchestra_musicians eom on oi.oi_id = eom.instrument_id
where (eom.event_id = 2 or eom.event_id is null)
order by oi.oi_id
```

You have to use orchestra_instruments as the base table, since that is the one you want all of the records for, even if no musician exists.  I can't imagine any reasons for using a Right join over a Left join, and Outer is implied.  Also, you have to allow event_id to either be 2 or null, because it cannot be 2 if there is no matching record to join.

Comment: The only necessary change is the `eom.event_id is null` part. In his statement he only asks for `event_id = 2`, but if there is no matching musician, event_id clearly isn't 2 but null and thus that instrument is not returned.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I've tried switching the base tables and it has no effect. I've copied your code with and without the null event_id in the where clause and it still acts as an inner join, doesn't show any nulls or bring over the piccolo.

Comment: @user1143767: Please show the statement you actually are using now. The statement provided by Fosco should work.

Comment: @user1143767 Have you run my query as provided, unmodified?

Comment: I've ran the EXACT statement you provided, however I had to modify oi.instrument_id to oi.oi_id (the column name in the oi table is oi_id, not instrument id) other than that, I didn't change anything. Do I need to setup foreign key relationships?

Comment: @user1143767 I edited the answer to adjust the column name...  Are you sure the values exist as you described?  There's no good explanation why this wouldn't work without being able to see the data in the tables...

Comment: Tried your revised query and still not working. I took some screenshots of the data in the two tables, the lookup table is sorted by instrument_id. Hope this helps: http://imgur.com/a/b7sKe#0  7- piccolo is the one that wont come through

Comment: seph, the problem is not that the query doesn't run (I renamed oi.instrument_name to the proper column [oi.oi_name]), the problem is that the results that are returned are results that are typical of an inner join, not an outerjoin. the piccolo doesn't show up with an outer join and null columns for everything else, like it should..

Comment: So I created another test table with just test_id, instrument_id, musician_id and I was able to successfully do an outer join on it against the orchestra_instruments table. so there's something going on in the events_orchestra_musicians table..

Comment: Update original post with some findings

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any records in `Event_Orchestra_Musicians` where `instrument_id=4` so you'll need to check for a `null` value from `eom` when doing a right outer join.

```
SELECT * FROM `event_orchestra_musicians` eom
right outer join `orchestra_instruments` oi on eom.instrument_id = oi.oi_id
where event_id = 2 or eom.instrument_id is null
order by instrument_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my complete setup. Maybe there something with your structure?

```
mysql> show columns from orchestra_instruments;
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| oi_id   | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| oi_name | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> show columns from event_orchestra_musicians;
+---------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| musician_id   | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| instrument_id | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| event_id      | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from orchestra_instruments;
+-------+---------+
| oi_id | oi_name |
+-------+---------+
|     1 | Violin  |
|     2 | Viola   |
|     3 | Harp    |
|     4 | Piccolo |
+-------+---------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from event_orchestra_musicians;
+-------------+---------------+----------+
| musician_id | instrument_id | event_id |
+-------------+---------------+----------+
|           1 |             1 |        2 |
|           2 |             1 |        2 |
|           3 |             3 |        2 |
|           4 |             2 |        2 |
+-------------+---------------+----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

select oi.oi_id, oi.oi_name, eom.musician_id
from orchestra_instruments oi
left join event_orchestra_musicians eom on oi.oi_id = eom.instrument_id
where (eom.event_id = 2 or eom.event_id is null)
order by oi.oi_id;

+-------+---------+-------------+
| oi_id | oi_name | musician_id |
+-------+---------+-------------+
|     1 | Violin  |           1 |
|     1 | Violin  |           2 |
|     2 | Viola   |           4 |
|     3 | Harp    |           3 |
|     4 | Piccolo |        NULL |
+-------+---------+-------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```